# Make ActiveX buttons not move with cells / Excel

Tags: excel, button, activexobject

Have a couple if ActiveX Command Buttons in a worksheet. When I hide some rows, they move with the cells and end up on top of each other. Which property should I use to tell them to just stay put?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the command button and select **Format Control**.
Go to the **Properties** tab and tick **Don't move or size with cells**.

*Edit after question accepted as answer*
To do this in VBA use:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim btn As Object
    Set btn = Sheet1.CommandButton1
    'Or
    'Set btn = Sheet1.OLEObjects("CommandButton1")
    
    btn.Placement = xlFreeFloating

End Sub
```

xlFreeFloating  (3) - Object is free floating.
xlMove  (2) -   Object is moved with the cells.
xlMoveAndSize   (1) -   Object is moved and sized with the cells.

[Using ActiveX Controls on Sheets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/Concepts/Controls-DialogBoxes-Forms/using-activex-controls-on-sheets)

Comment: Is there a way to set this via VBA?

Comment: @codeEnthusiast Have updated to show VBA solution.